# Compiler error "compiler is out of heap space" when calling `delete` operator in the destructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, delete-operator

I wrote a class named "**TreeContainer**". My aim is to design a tree container which keeps contents in a tree-like hierarchy. Every tree container is supposed to work like folders/directories in the file system. A folder (tree) can have sub-folders (sub-trees) and other files (sub-items).

I included it in another source file, say its name is "**TreeUser.cpp**". When I try to debug/run my project, Visual Studio compiles project source files one by one and I see which file is currently compiling in the "Output" panel of the IDE. When it comes to the **TreeUser.cpp** file, it takes TOO MUCH time on it. And it finally gives the fatal error below, and the compiling stops.

> Error  C1060   compiler is out of heap space
>   [*Project Name Here*]
>   [*Path To Visual Studio Installation Here*]\visual studio\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\xmemory0   962

The code of the class is below.

**TreeContainer.cpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

template <class T>
class TreeContainer
{
    public:
        using SubTreeContainerType = std::vector<TreeContainer<T *> *>;
        using SubItemContainerType = std::vector<T *>;

        TreeContainer();
        ~TreeContainer();

        // ... (Lots of member functions here. Removing or keeping them has no effect.)

    private:
        SubTreeContainerType SubTrees;
        SubItemContainerType SubItems;

};

template <class T>
TreeContainer<T>::TreeContainer()
    : SubTrees(), SubItems()
{
}

template <class T>
TreeContainer<T>::~TreeContainer()
{
    for (typename SubTreeContainerType::iterator it=SubTrees.begin(); it!=SubTrees.end(); ++it)
    {
        //delete *it; (I get the error when I uncomment this line.)
    }
    for (typename SubItemContainerType::iterator it=SubItems.begin(); it!=SubItems.end(); ++it)
    {
        delete *it;
    }
}
```

After many trials, I figured out that the line in the destructor is causing the problem. Removing it removes the problem. But I need that line in order to clean up the memory.

In that line, I am calling the `delete` operator on the contents of the container `SubTrees`. It is supposed to recursively call the destructors on every sub-tree. Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug in Visual Studio.

IDE Version: Visual Studio Community 2017 15.7.4

Command Line Options:

> /permissive- /GS /W3 /wd"4290" /wd"5040" /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "SC_DEBUG" /D "_SILENCE_CXX17_CODECVT_HEADER_DEPRECATION_WARNING" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /std:c++17 /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\Project Name.pch" /diagnostics:classic

Comment: If these containers are meant to own the objects in question, you should really be using `std::unique_ptr<T>`, not `T*`. That way at least, you wouldn't need to roll your own destructor for this object. Even if `std::unique_ptr` is wrong for your task, you should still be restructuring your code to obey proper RAII convention, in not having a single object be *directly* responsible for the lifetime of more than one resource, and instead delegating responsibilities for each resource to its own object.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you create infinitely many classes from your template, because `SubTreeContainerType` of `TreeContainer<T>` references `TreeContainer<T *>` (container of `T` pointers).

And the destructor needs the destructor of the vector of subtrees, which in turn needs the destructor of `TreeContainer<T *>`, which needs the destructor of `TreeContainer<T **>` etc. pp.

Solution:

```
using SubTreeContainerType = std::vector<TreeContainer<T> *>;
```

Or, if you really want the subtree container to refer to pointers to `T`, add a template specialization for pointers that breaks the recursion before implementing the methods.